# Interpret Interaction Effects in Negative Binomial Regression

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, interpretation, negative-binomial-distribution

I have two questions regarding the interpretation of interaction effects in a negative binomial regression model. The model uses the number of people arriving at a hotel per hour as the dependent variable. The focal independent variables for this question are temperature (in degrees Celsius) and cloud cover (in percentage).  I am testing for a potential moderating effect of weekend days (as opposed to week days).

Q1: See the below results (f.l.t.r.: beta, beta exponentiated, standard error, t-value, significance). Is the following interpretation of the results correct:

For every one degree Celsius increase in temperature, the conditional mean number of arrivals decreases with 0.7%. On weekend days (weekend = 1) this effect increases by 1.2%, i.e. the relationship becomes less negative. **On weekend days, the combined effect is 0.993 * 1.012 = 1.005, so the effect actually becomes positive on weekend days.**

[image]

[image]

Q2: For the interaction with cloud cover, the main effect is not significant. How does this change the interpretation of the effects? Is it correct to state that we can only infer that the effect of cloud cover is less negative during weekend days (i.e. it changes positively by 0.3%) - or can I not infer anything given that the main effect is not significant?

[image]
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your interpretation refers to the log link which is not the canonical one, and  for which the interpretation is not so clear. It seems surprising not to include a `Weekend` main effect.

Comment: Also remember that the main effects do not have a straightforward interpretation when an interaction term is in the model (and without centering, are likely meaningless). The significant interaction is also telling you that the main effect of cloud cover isn't constant between the weekend and weekdays. Search for other posts of the issue of interpreting interactions in regression models.